# Need help to Make a live updatable Timer using jQuery and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

it's quite a few days i keep bouncing around different questions here on stack overflow and other programming websites/forums but i can't find the answer to my problem.

Basically what i want to do, is to create a timer that can be updated in real time by another web page.

Due to server limitations i am forced to use jQuery, javascript and PHP to do so and i can't use any more advanced languages.

I can't get past the problem of having somewhere in my code something to turn in NaN.

Below i will post the entirety of the front-end code.

Could someone tell me why my code isn't working?

```js
var firstTimer=10;
var x=10;

jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: "myapi.php",
    data: "",
    success: function (data){
        firstTimer= data.minuti;
        x= data.minuti;
    }
});
    

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        jQuery.ajax({
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'GET',
          url: "myapi.php",
          data: "",
          success: function (data){
              x= data.minuti;
          }        
        });

        if(firstTimer != x){
            location.reload(true);            
        }

        if (--timer < 0) {
            alert("TIME EXPIRED");
        }
    }, 1000);
}
   



window.onload = function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: "myapi.php",
        data: "",
        success: function (data){
            firstTimer= data.minuti;
            x= data.minuti;
        }
        
    });

    minuti = Number(firstTimer);
    fiveMinutes = 60 * minuti,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><span id="time"></span></div>
```

Comment: Give us the name of the file in which your code resides, please, and the content of the timerapi.php. And you'll have to provide a detailed explanation regarding the workflow and about the var names that you are using. From a first sight, you are expecting ajax results to be used properly by the code lines that follow. But this is not how it works. If an ajax runs, the next code line after it can/will be executed before the ajax request returns any results. So the following code lines have to be moved into the `success` callback.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you seem to have run into the glorious wonders of asynchronity. Your code is structured as if it were run top to bottom in a sequencial manner, however, caused by your use of asynchronous requests, this is not the case. Please refer to [Eloquent Javascript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) for a much more, ehem, eloquent explanation of the matter.

In short: the callbacks to your `$.ajax()` calls will be run *after* the surrounding code, including the lines following them. This means that `minuti = Number(firstTimer);` within your `window.onload` handler is actually executed before `minuti` has been set from the server. Making sure that all code is executed only after the asynchronous calls have been made may also solve your `NaN` troubles. You can put in a couple of `console.log` calls in various places to actually get a grip of the current values of the used variables.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, really got me past all my problems as soon as i understood the simple thing i had to do.